# Magento 2 how can magento core module save product details?

Tags: magento2, products, save

I'm writing a module for setting tier price for segments by modelling tier price for groups in Magento 2's core module. But I got confused when I following the codes for saving product details in the core module. I found that the core module `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save` uses `$product->save();` to save the product.

Then I got

```
 public function save()
    {

        $this->_getResource()->save($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

in Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
and `save()` in `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
       if ($object->isDeleted()) {
            return $this->delete($object);
        }

        $this->beginTransaction();

        try {
            if (!$this->isModified($object)) {
                $this->processNotModifiedSave($object);
                $this->commit();
                $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
                return $this;
            }
            $object->validateBeforeSave();
            $object->beforeSave();
            if ($object->isSaveAllowed()) {
                $this->_serializeFields($object);
                $this->_beforeSave($object);
                $this->_checkUnique($object);
                $this->objectRelationProcessor->validateDataIntegrity($this->getMainTable(), $object->getData());
                if ($this->isObjectNotNew($object)) {
                    $this->updateObject($object);
                } else {
                    $this->saveNewObject($object);
                }
                $this->unserializeFields($object);
                $this->processAfterSaves($object);
            }
            $this->addCommitCallback([$object, 'afterCommitCallback'])->commit();
            $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->rollBack();
            $object->setHasDataChanges(true);
            throw $e;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

But I can't find any details about saving the product details, the `save()` is all about logging, when I comment all the codes inside the `save()` method , the Magento can still save the product details.

Anyone can tell me where the Magento does the action for saving product details? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product is a EAV entity and using `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity::save` method to persist attributes in DB